# How to Copy a list from one class to another class

Tags: c++, list

My question is how can i copy a list from one class to another?

I´d try something like:

```
list<int> GetList();

list<int> CSolid::GetList()
{
    return list<int>(List);
}
```

And then

```
list<int> NewList = Class::GetList();
```

I would try this like this but im not sure if this is right. Are there better solutions ? (if this is wrong whats the right way to do it?

Comment: Maybe you should just try it? I'm not sure what you are trying though. `Class::GetList();` is a call to a static method. And `return list<int>(List);` is probably one wrapper too much, depending on what `List` is. And lastly `list<int> GetList();` as written defines a free function and no member function.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about using built in data structures in C++ is that mostly they work as you would want them when you use primitive types such as int/floats etc... 
I'd probably use std::list pre-defined copy-constructor the following way:

```
class SomeClassWithIntList
{
    public:
    SomeClassWithIntList(const std::list<int>& _inputList = {})
    {
            m_NumberList = std::list<int>(_inputList);
    }
    void PrintList()
    {
        for(auto i : m_NumberList)
        {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::list<int> GetList()
    {
        return m_NumberList;
    }

    private:
    std::list<int> m_NumberList;
};

int main()
{
    // Use class constructor to input a given list to the std::list<int>
    // constructor
    SomeClassWithIntList test1 = SomeClassWithIntList({1,2,3});
    test1.PrintList();
    // Here we created test2 with an empty list
    SomeClassWithIntList test2 = SomeClassWithIntList();
    test2.PrintList();
    // We can use the constructor to copy the list
    test2 = SomeClassWithIntList(test1.GetList());
    test2.PrintList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: New to stack overflow, fixed my post :)